# Imitating screenshot flash animation on iOS

Tags: ios

Im looking for a way to copy the "blink" animation, that is played when pressing home+lock.

Does anyone know if this animation is available somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On an iOS device you take a screenshot when you press home + lock and the screen flashes white. Do you mean this effect? If so, try this:

Add a `UIView` with a white background color to your view hierarchy such that it covers the whole screen. Then, start an animation that fades the opacity of this view to zero. On completion, remove the view from its superview:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 
                 animations: ^{
                               whiteView.alpha = 0.0;
                             }
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                               [whiteView removeFromSuperview];
                             }
];
```

Comment: Tried this, but it still does not affect the entire screen like the home+lock function. I need to have the whiteView on top of all other views for it to work, but then i cannot click buttons and stuff. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want the entire screen to flash, add the white view to the application's `UIWindow` and set the frame accordingly. All buttons work all the time, if you add the white view just in the moment before the animation starts and remove it on completion as suggested - except during the short flash. Would this be a problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    for (UIView *view2 in self.view.subviews) {
        view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    for (UIView *view2 in self.view.subviews) {
        view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}];
```

Comment: You might want to blink all views (which can be found via a for loop), to increase the effect of the animation.

Comment: Great! This is now the best solution I can think of to this situation.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique I am sure it works, perhaps I did something wrong. I tried testing this on a UIView with no subviews (just wanted to test the code, no I left out the for loops). self.view.backgroundColor is white. But no blink effect.

Comment: Thanks alot abdullah, this works fine to some extend. I want to have this animation on top of my MKMapkit. But as it is now, the code has no effect since none of the background is shown. Hope you get what i mean.

Comment: I don't understand what the code is supposed to do. You start two animations at the same time with the same duration to animate the same property (background color) to different target values. Looks like undefined behavior to me. Further, you end up with a different state than you started with - all the views have background color black or white no matter what background color they had before the animation started.

Answer (score 3):

These examples gave me inspiration, but did not give me the desired effect. This is my attempt, looks pretty close to the real deal.

```
func mimicScreenShotFlash() {

    let aView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
    aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(aView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        aView.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: { (done) -> Void in
            aView.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found very easy way to imitate exactly the Screenshot Flash Apple uses. I wish everyone try it at least once.

```
UIView * flashView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
flashView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:flashView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0.3 options:0 animations:^{
      flashView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
        [flashView removeFromSuperview]; 
     }];
}
```

Comment: What if i need to do this in continuous loop? or same effect 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with the current solutions:

1. putting views over other views can (in my experience with UICollectionView and other crap) trigger autolayout. Autolayout is bad. Autolayout makes the machine do a burst of work and can have side effects other than just calculating for no reason other than to burn CPU and battery. So, you don't want to give it reasons to autolayout, for instance, adding a subview to a view that really, really cares about keeping itself laid out nicely.
2. your view doesn't cover the whole screen necessarily, so if you want to flash the whole screen, you're better off using a UIWindow ... this should insulate from any view controllers that are touchy about having subviews added

This is my implementation, a category on UIView. I've included methods to take a screenshot before flashing the window, and saving it to the camera roll afterwards. Note that UIWindow seems to want to do its own animations when being added, it will normally fade in over maybe a third of a second. There may be a better way of telling it not to do this.

```
// stupid blocks
typedef void (^QCompletion)(BOOL complete);

@interface UIView (QViewAnimation)
+ (UIImage *)screenshot; // whole screen 
+ (void)flashScreen:(QCompletion)complete;
- (UIImage *)snapshot; // this view only
- (void)takeScreenshotAndFlashScreen;
@end

@implementation UIView (QViewAnimation)

+ (UIImage *)screenshot;
{

    NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
    UIWindow *window = nil;
    if (windows.count) {
        window = windows[0];
        return [window snapshot];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Screenshot failed.");
        return nil;
    }
}

- (UIImage *)snapshot;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

+ (void)flashScreen:(QCompletion)complete;
{
    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGRect bounds = screen.bounds;
    UIWindow * flash = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    flash.alpha = 1;
    flash.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    [flash makeKeyAndVisible];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
            flash.alpha = 0;
        }
                         completion: ^(BOOL finished)
        {
            flash.hidden = YES;
            [flash autorelease];
            if (complete) {
                complete(YES);
            }

        }];
}

- (void)takeScreenshotAndFlashScreen;
{
    UIImage *image = [UIView screenshot];
    [UIView flashScreen:^(BOOL complete){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0),
                       ^{
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,@selector(imageDidFinishSaving:withError:context:),nil);
        });
    }];
}

- (void)imageDidFinishSaving:(UIImage *)image
                   withError:(NSError *)error
                     context:(void *)context;
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        // send an alert that the image saved
    });
}

@end
```