# how to capture complete screenshot of view in ios9

Tags: ios, screenshot

for capture screenshot is use the below code

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenSize, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

but it gives the error  >> : CGImageCreateWithImageProvider: invalid image provider: NULL.

i am not understand what it is.

please help!!
how to capture the screenshot in ios9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

New [API](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates%3A) has been added since iOS 7, that should provide efficient way of getting snapshot

`snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`: renders the view into a UIView with unmodifiable content

`resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets :` same thing, but with resizable insets

```
  drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:
```

: same thing if you need all subviews to be drawn too (like labels, buttons...)

You can use the UIView returned for any UI effect, or render in into an image like you did if you need to export.

**Solution 2:**

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[myUIView.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following function, its working for me perfectly:

```
-(void) TakeScreenShot
{
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];
}
```

Also if you want to imitate screenshot animation please refer to this link, i have provided code for it.
[Imitating screenshot flash animation on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080386/imitating-screenshot-flash-animation-on-ios/34694704#34694704)